# Optimization algorithms for piecewise-constant and similar ill-defined functions

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, heuristics, approximation, nonlinear-optimization

I have a function which takes as inputs n-dimensional (say n=10) vectors whose components are real numbers varying from 0 to a large positive number A say 50,000, ends included. For any such vector the function outputs an integer from 1 to say B=100. I have this function and want to find its global minima.

Broadly speaking there are algorithmic, iterative and heuristics based approaches to tackle such optimization problem. Which are the best techniques suggested to solve this problem? I am looking for suggestions to algorithms or active research papers that i can implement from scratch to solve such problems. I have already given up hope on existing optimization functions that ship with Matlab/python. I am hoping to read experience of others working with approximation/heuristic algorithms to optimize such ill-defined functions.

I ran `fmincon`, `fminsearch`, `fminunc` in Matlab but they fail to optimize the function. The function is ill-defined according to their definitions. Matlab says this for `fmincon`:

```
Initial point is a local minimum that satisfies the constraints.

Optimization completed because at the initial point, the objective function is non-decreasing 
in feasible directions to within the selected value of the optimality tolerance, and 
constraints are satisfied to within the selected value of the constraint tolerance.
```

Problem arises because this function has piecewise-constant behavior. If a vector V is assigned to a number say 65, changing its components very slightly may not have any change. Such ill-defined behavior is to be well-expected because of pigeon-hole principle. The domain of function is unlimited whereas range is just a bunch of numbers.

I also wish to clarify one issue that may arise. Suppose i do gradient descent on a starting point `x0` and my next `x` that i get from GD-iteration has some components lie outside the domain [0,50000], then what happens? So actually the domain is circular. So a vector of size 3 like [30;5432;50432] becomes [30;5432;432]. This is automatically taken care of so that there is no worry about iterations finding a vector outside the domain.

Comment: This is nasty. May be a derivative free optimization method or a global solver can do better.

Comment: Any chance to combine function evaluation and minimization? I.e. not to use the function as a black box, but use its structure to find the minimum?

Comment: Nothing you have said so far about the function rules out the possibility that it has the value 0 everywhere except at x1=42, x2=69.  Now think about how a solver could possibly maximise this function without either (a) knowing more about it or (b) trying every possible value in its domain.

Comment: To add more context, i am tasked with minimizing this function. It was coded before i joined the group as an intern and was made available to me as a standalone executable file. My task is to explore whether such techniques are possible that will minimize it as a black-box function. Based on comments, it seems not. So any resource that can guide me in the right direction will be helpful.

Comment: @KarstenW. I guess the function does not have any other special feature than that it assumes constancy on small neighborhoods as pointed out earlier. But i may be wrong. Then your idea can be very helpful. Can you point some resources in that direction where others have done the same?

Comment: Assume the function is a linear combination of floor functions on components of the input, then it might be possible to formulate your minimization as a MIP. Or maybe you can transform your function to a nicer function, minimize that and substitute back your result.

Comment: If you don't know anything about the function, the best you can do is keep trying random inputs, and keep the best result found so far.  If you know that inputs that are close to each other (according to some distance metric) usually produce outputs that are close to each other, it might be slightly more efficient to make sure the next random input you try isn't too close to any previous random input.